# Windows 7 Upgrade Fail from Home Premium to Ultimate Professional

Tags: windows-7, upgrade

I had a hard drive crash, which meant I had to install a new HDD in my Dell 64-Bit XPS 1350 (lovely computer).  I had previously been running Windows 7 Ultimate Professional which I had upgraded from the OEM Win 7 Home Premium by means of a disk I purchased from my university.

Using the Recovery disk from Dell I installed Windows 7 Home Premium successfully on the new hard drive, but when I have tried to upgrade via my disk to Ultimate it installs the whole thing, says its complete, but when I reboot, tells me:

"This version of Windows could not be installed. Your previous version of Windows has been restored, and you can continue to use it."

I've installed the drivers from Dell's driver disk, but still to no avail.  I've also used Driver Robot to update all my drivers.

I can't find a .dmp file anywhere under 
C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources

but I did find this file under
C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther.

setupact.log    https://www.dropbox.com/s/yzy7fhkxlzc235y/setupact.log

If anyone could please advise me what I need to do to fix Windows so it will upgrade properly, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: BTW, I have run Windows Upgrade advisor, and it has passed everything.

Answer (score 0):

I did find this in the log. You selected "clean install" instead of Upgrade. You cannot clean install using upgrade media.

> DoComplianceChecks: CheckSkuCompatibility not satisfied (To upgrade from one edition of Windows 7 to another edition of Windows 7, use Windows Anytime Upgrade. Cancel the upgrade, open the Start menu, and search for Windows Anytime Upgrade.) 2012-10-10 21:45:13, Info       [0x080021] MIG    IsCompliantForUpgrade: failed
>
> 2012-10-10 21:45:13, Info                  MIG    Callback_Compliance: compatibility report was skipped.
>
> 2012-10-10 21:45:13, Warning               UI     [APPCOMPAT UI] Got CallbackAppCompatProgress without compat progress page active
> 2012-10-10 21:45:13, Info       [0x080043] MIG    Callback_Compliance: Not a compliant system
>
> 2012-10-10 21:45:13, Info       [0x08003e] MIG    Not a compliant system, upgrade is disabled
>
> 2012-10-10 21:45:13, Info       [0x090056] PANTHR **User selected clean install option**

Comment: Ah, ok, thank you.
However, when I go to upgrade rather than install, it forces me to use Anytime Windows Upgrade, which then doesn't accept the passcode on my disk sleeve.  I bought it legally from my university computer centre - although when I bought it, it was from the US, and now I am restoring my computer in the US.  Does that make a difference?

Comment: It rejects my passcode even if I am offline, so I don't see how it could know I'm not in the US.

Comment: anytime upgrade key is different than upgrade disc purchase key, use the disc and do an upgrade, not a clean install.

Comment: I want to use the disc to upgrade, but every time I do, it says: 

"To upgrade from one edition of Windows 7 to another edition of Windows 7, use Windows Anytime Upgrade. Cancel the upgrade, open the Start menu, and search for Windows Anytime Upgrade."

That's why I tried the install option instead of upgrade.  What can I do to stop it forcing me to use Anytime Upgrade?

Comment: That is not what you posted in your question ""This version of Windows could not be installed. Your previous version of Windows has been restored, and you can continue to use it.""

Comment: Yes, that's right, I have received both error messages.  First, the one directly above, forbidding me to upgrade from disc, and directing me to Anytime Upgrade.  Which doesn't accept the disc product key, as you pointed out.  As a result I tried to do the clean install which produced the error code I orginally posted.

Comment: You may need to contact Microsoft to sort this out.

Comment: Done.  Problem solved, it was a North/Latin America disk, and I was updating in Germany.  Solved with an IP masker.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wow, did not know it was region specific, wonder if it would complete if disconnected from the internet while upgrading.